# Replicating Java's DecimalFormat in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, formatting

I am trying to replicate a subset of Java's `DecimalFormat` class. Below is what I've come up with. Does this look right to everyone?

```
public class DecimalFormat : NumberFormat
{
    int _maximumFractionDigits;
    int _minimumFractionDigits;

    string _format;

    void RebuildFormat ()
    {           
        _format = "{0:0.";

        _format += new string ('0', _minimumFractionDigits);
        if (_maximumFractionDigits > _minimumFractionDigits) {
            _format += new string ('#', _maximumFractionDigits -
                         _minimumFractionDigits);
        }

        _format += "}";
    }

    public override string format (object value)
    {
        return string.Format (_format, value);
    }

    public override void setMaximumFractionDigits (int n)
    {
        _maximumFractionDigits = n;
        RebuildFormat ();
    }

    public override void setMinimumFractionDigits (int n)
    {
        _minimumFractionDigits = n;
        RebuildFormat ();
    }

    public override void setGroupingUsed (bool g)
    {
    }

    public static NumberFormat getInstance ()
    {
        return new DecimalFormat ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting decimals is ridiculously easy in .NET.  Why would you want to impersonate a Java class that makes it more complicated?

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Why do people use SQL Server? Why are roses red? We all have our business reasons. In my case, I have a lot of battle tested code from Java with very specific formatting requirements. I don't want to toss all that domain knowledge out the window.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the easiest way would be to use `ToString("N2");` where 2 is replaced by the number of decimal places you want.

If you really want minimum and maximum, you could also use `IFormattable`'s `ToString("#,#.00##", CultureInfo.CurrenCulture);` which would give you a number with a minimum of two decimal places and a maximum of four, with comma digit separators on the integral part.

Comment: But how does that respect Minimum and Maximum? That's just setting Maximum.

Comment: (1) Object doesn't have a 1 arg ToString method. (2) Min and Max change at run time. That's what my code is doing. Please read the question, I am looking for confirmation that this is the right format string to replicate DecimalFormat.

Comment: Object doesn't have a 1-arg ToString method, but all the number classes do.  And `IFormattable` has a 2-arg version, which is the same as the number classes 1-arg version with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` passed as the second value.